# Scraping and displaying xml formatted string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, loops, xml-parsing

I have the following string which is already parsed from a xml page:

`var info = '<Message>Fermata 1431 -  Linea 202 -> 08:57  Linea 201 -> 09:02  Linea 256B -> 09:02  Linea 202 -> 09:05  Linea R2 -> 09:06  Linea 201 -> 09:13  Linea 201 -> 09:18   </Message>'`

i have to strip < Message > tags in pure javascript, i'm using

```
 info = data.match(/<Message>(.*?)<\/Message>/g);
```

but it still displays Message tags, seems i dont use correct regexp.

Overall i need to print this, all in pure javascript, no jquery unfortunately :

`202 at 08:57
201 at 09:02
256B at 09:02
202 at 09:05
R2 at09:06
201 at 09:13
201 at 09:18`

in php i was using this code and it works but i need to convert in javacript:

```
$scraped_data = scrape_between($info, "<Message>", "</Message>")
$parts = explode('Linea', $scraped_data);

        //start from 1, as the 1st item in array is 'Fermata 1431 - '
        for($i=1;$i<count($parts);$i++){
            echo '<p>Linea ' . str_replace('->', 'at', $parts[$i]) . '</p>';
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following..

```
var info = '<Message>Fermata 1431 -  Linea 202 -> 08:57  Linea 201 -> 09:02  Linea 256B -> 09:02  Linea 202 -> 09:05  Linea R2 -> 09:06  Linea 201 -> 09:13  Linea 201 -> 09:18   </Message>';
var arr  = info.match(/[\w\d]+\s*->\s*[\d:]+/g);

for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = arr[i].replace('->', 'at');
  console.log('Linea ' + arr[i]);
}
```

Output

```
Linea 202 at 08:57
Linea 201 at 09:02
Linea 256B at 09:02
Linea 202 at 09:05
Linea R2 at 09:06
Linea 201 at 09:13
Linea 201 at 09:18
```

Comment: thanks @hwnd this solution better fits my needs.
however, i edited a little but it shows me a comma before each line.
this is the code im using:

`var data = '<Message>Fermata 1431 -  Linea 202 -> 08:57  Linea 201 -> 09:02  Linea 256B -> 09:02  Linea 202 -> 09:05  Linea R2 -> 09:06  Linea 201 -> 09:13  Linea 201 -> 09:18   </Message>';

var arr  = data.match(/[\w\d]+\s*->\s*[\d:]+/g);
for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = arr[i].replace('->', 'at');
   arr[i] = arr[i]+'\n';
  
}
console.log(arr);`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

```
<script>

var info = '<Message>Fermata 1431 -  Linea 202 -> 08:57  Linea 201 -> 09:02  Linea 256B -> 09:02  Linea 202 -> 09:05  Linea R2 -> 09:06  Linea 201 -> 09:13  Linea 201 -> 09:18   </Message>';

var re = /([\w\d]+)\s->\s(\d+:\d+)/g;
var match;
var res = [];
while (match = re.exec(info)){
    res.push(match[1] + " at " + match[2]);
}
console.log(res);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
<script>

var data = '<Message>Fermata 1431 -  Linea 202 -> 08:57  Linea 201 -> 09:02  Linea 256B ->  09:02  Linea 202 -> 09:05  Linea R2 -> 09:06  Linea 201 -> 09:13  Linea 201 -> 09:18     </Message>';
info = data.match(/([\w\d]+)\s->\s(\d+:\d+)/g);
</script>
```

And in info you get the array of values which you need.